# Create 3 virtual interfaces that can ping6 each other

Tags: linux, bridge, tap

In Linux, how can you create 3 virtual interfaces that are bridged together through a virtual switch so that they can ping6 each other?

What I did:

```
tunctl -t tap1i
tunctl -t tap2i
tunctl -t tap3i
ip addr add scope link fd80::1/56 dev tap1i
ip addr add scope link fd80::2/56 dev tap2i
ip addr add scope link fd80::3/56 dev tap3i
ip link set dev tap1i up
ip link set dev tap2i up
ip link set dev tap3i up

brctl addbr r2
brctl addif r2 tap1i tap2i tap3i
```

The problem is that `brctl showstp r2` shows the ports as "disabled" instead of "forwarding" as expected, and ping doesn't work.

What I want is for `ping6 -I tap1i fd80::2` to work.

Thanks.